# Import new data from a text file based on certain field criteria

Tags: excel, vba, import-from-csv

I have a little VB knowledge but this one is way beyond my scope. This is a multipart problem I am trying to find a solution.

We have a tab delineated text file with 11 fields that is constantly updated by another program. We would like to copy/import just two fields of that data, let’s say fields #9 & #11 into Excel but only bring in the new data since the previous import. So if initially there are 5 lines of data, that would come in and populate the first 5 rows and 2 columns in a worksheet. Then subsequently it would bring in only anything added after the initial copy/import. I have been able to write a routine that simply copies everything and overwrites what is there but this is not what we want.

The next part of this is that based on certain criteria, the data will be copied/imported into certain columns. The criteria variables will be in fields #2 and #6. So for example, if field #2 = 1, and field #6 = 2, then fields #9 & #11 will go in columns A & B. If field #2 = 2 and field #6 = 1, then fields #9 & #11 will go into columns C&D. There would most likely be 6 possible combinations of those variables (1/1, ½, 1/3, 2/1, 2/2, 2/3) so columns A-L could be populated. Note that field #9 could be blank in which case it would just bring in field #11 or just copy the blank text. These variable numbers could be referenced to cells in the workbook where we select which variables will correspond to which columns. For example if we wanted columns A & B to contain the data with the variables 1 & 2, cells G1 & H1 could have #1 & #2 in their cells if that is helpful. There may be times when we want that variable combo of 2/1 to go into cells A & B.

Here is the text file:

```txt
0 1 2 0 0 1 b 1648 1648 9:55:02.61 09:55:03
0 2 5 0 0 1 b 1648 1659 9:57:45.70 09:57:46
0 2 7 0 0 2 b 1649 1649 9:58:09.84 09:58:10
0 3 8 0 0 1 s 9:58:09.87 09:58:10
0 1 9 0 0 1 b 1656 1656 9:58:13.80 09:58:15
0 1 11 0 0 1 b 1657 1657 9:58:19.88 09:58:20
0 3 12 0 0 1 s 9:58:19.93 09:58:20
0 1 13 0 0 1 b 1663 1663 9:58:25.77 09:58:26
0 1 14 0 0 2 s 9:58:25.78 09:58:26
0 1 15 0 0 2 s 9:59:22.40 09:59:23
0 2 16 0 0 1 b 1664 1664 9:59:22.41 09:59:23
0 2 17 0 0 2 s 1671 1671 9:59:26.33 09:59:27
```

This is the text file and what the worksheet should look like

[image]

The last part is ideally this routine would only run when the text file has been updated but I am not sure how possible that is. Otherwise I can just put this on a timer that will run every minute or so.

Being a bit of neophyte with VBA I have found this forum to be an awesome resource so I hope I have explained this correctly. If this info is already posted somewhere please point me in that direction. I am always willing to learn but this one is bit beyond me right now.

As always, many thanks in advance.

I have a little VB knowledge but this one is way beyond my scope. This is a multipart problem I am trying to find a solution.

This is code we use to import the entire text file

```vb
Public Sub ImportSRTfile()
     Dim strSpec As String, i As Long, colToRet As Long, lastR As Long
     Dim arrSp As Variant, arrRez() As String, arrInt As Variant, j As Long, K As Long
     Dim FSO As Object, txtStr As Object, strText As String 'no need of any reference
    
      Set shT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("srt_data")
      Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      strSpec = "C:\srt_timing\srt_data_acquisition_module\srt_backup_timer_data.txt"
      If Dir(strSpec) <> "" Then 'check if file exists
        Set txtStr = FSO.OpenTextFile(strSpec)
            strText = txtStr.ReadAll
        txtStr.Close
      End If
      arrSp = Split(strText, vbCrLf)
    
        colToRet = 11 'Number of columns to be returned
        lastR = shT.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A:A
        'arrRez is dimensioned from 0 to UBound(arrSp) only for lastR = 1
        ReDim arrRez(IIf(lastR = 1, 0, 1) To UBound(arrSp), colToRet - 1)
        For i = IIf(lastR = 1, 0, 1) To UBound(arrSp) 'Only in case of larR = 1, the
                                                      'head of the table is load in arr
          arrInt = Split(arrSp(i), vbTab)  'each strText line is split in an array
          If UBound(arrInt) > colToRet - 1 Then
              For j = 0 To colToRet - 1
                  arrRez(i, j) = arrInt(j) 'each array element is loaded in the arrRez
              Next j
          End If
        Next i
        'The array is dropped in the dedicated range (calculated using Resize):
        shT.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, lastR, lastR + 1)).Resize(UBound(arrRez, 1), _
                                                    UBound(arrRez, 2) + 1).Value = arrRez
        
End Sub
```

Comment: please show code you have done so far! For not importing "old" data you have two possibiites: either you mark in each line in the text-file ,and filter those out, or you save in a cell in the excel, which line was the last read in the last go, and skip all line til there next time

Comment: This question reads more like a full specification - you should consider breaking it down to focus on one thing at a time.  If you have *any* existing code to add to your post, that's going to increase your chances of getting help here.

Comment: Tim - I was kinda thinking the same thing. If I can get some help with the first two parts separately I could put everything together.

Comment: If any column is empty, will it always be colums `8` and `9` or are there other surprises? Does your data have headers? When you use `arrSp = Split(strText, vbCrLf)`, does the last row contain only empty elements? On a side note, the variable `shT` is not declared.

Comment: Just columns 8 & 9 are the ones that could potentially be empty. There usually are headers but for now simply col1, col2, col3, etc will work. Yes, the last row will always be empty.

Comment: What does *"but only bring in the new data since the previous import"* mean? Are you saying that there could be duplicates or just that you don't want to overwrite data? Is the new data appended in each column right below the old data, or does it start in the first available worksheet row leaving above empty cells in some columns i.e. looking at your screenshot, would the new data in all columns start in row 6?